# Failed to run jar file

Tags: java

I create jar file with command.

```
$jar -cvf A.jar A.class
```

I tried executing

```
$java -jar A.jar
```

I am getting below error.(Before adding "Main-class : A" to manifest.mf)

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from A.jar
```

contents of MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Created-By: 1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: A
```

Now i  am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't need to specify an Manifest file when you create a jar, but as you want to start your jar by launching `java -jar` you must specify your own manifest which details where is the class containing the `main()` method.

In order to do this you have to create a file containing this line :

```
Main-Class: A
```

(I suppose A is your class containing your main method, if it isn't the case specify the FQN of your desired class)

and create your jar with the following command :

```
jar cfm A.jar yourFileContainingMain-Class A.class
```

For example :

```
//Mac-Makkhdyn:~ Makkhdyn$ cat A.java
public class A{
public static void main(String... args){
System.out.println("lol");
}
}
//Mac-Makkhdyn:~ Makkhdyn$ cat manifest 
Main-Class: A
//Mac-Makkhdyn:~ Makkhdyn$ javac A.java
//Mac-Makkhdyn:~ Makkhdyn$ jar cvfm A.jar manifest A.class 
added manifest
adding: A.class(in = 399) (out= 278)(deflated 30%)
//Mac-Makkhdyn:~ Makkhdyn$ java -jar A.jar
lol
```

---

After your edit :

You **must** have a `main()` method in your `A` class you want to launch. Check the link below.

---

**Resources :**

- [oracle.com - Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Answer (score 1):

You also need a [manifest](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html) file inside the jar.